# Замена реального переноса строки на последовательность символов "\n" в PHP

Tags: php, строки

Есть переменная `$sms_text`. 
Вывод `var_dump($sms_text);`:

```
string(358) "Не работают:
№*****, ДО наименование – с 00.00.2016 г., (СОБ, ОСТиТ, Касса, Прочее);
№*****, ДО наименование – с 00.00.2016 г., (СОБ, ОСТиТ, Касса, Прочее);
№*****, ДО наименование – с 00.00.2016 г., (СОБ, ОСТиТ, Касса, Прочее);"
```

Подскажите, как заменить все переносы строки на символ `\n`, т.к. данный текст корректно не распознается парсером?

**UPD:**
Т.е. надо чтобы в данной переменной вместо переносов был именно символ \n, например:

```
"Не работают:\n№*****, ДО наименование – с 00.00.2016 г., (СОБ, ОСТиТ, Касса, Прочее);\n№*****, ДО наименование – с 00.00.2016 г., (СОБ, ОСТиТ, Касса, Прочее);\n№*****, ДО наименование – с 00.00.2016 г., (СОБ, ОСТиТ, Касса, Прочее);"
```

Comment: `$sms_text = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $sms_text);`

Comment: @mnv, возможно я не правильно написал, но надо чтобы в данной переменной вместо переносов был именно символ \n, например: `"Не работают:\n№*****, ДО наименование – с 00.00.2016 г., (СОБ, ОСТиТ, Касса, Прочее);\n№*****, ДО наименование – с 00.00.2016 г., (СОБ, ОСТиТ, Касса, Прочее);\n№*****, ДО наименование – с 00.00.2016 г., (СОБ, ОСТиТ, Касса, Прочее);"` После обработки функцией, что вы привели, все осталось также

Comment: Тогда `$sms_text = str_replace("\n", "\\n", $sms_text);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто замените перенос строки на нужные символы:

```
$sms_text = str_replace("\r", "", str_replace("\n", "\\n", $sms_text));
```

Comment: @mvn, сделал так: `$sms_text = str_replace("\n", "\\n\\r", $sms_text);`. Строка осталось все равно с переносами, + символы туда вставились: `"Не работают:<br>
\n\r№*****, ДО наименование – с 00.00.2016 г., (СОБ, ОСТиТ, Касса, Прочее);<br>
\n\r№*****, ДО наименование – с 00.00.2016 г., (СОБ, ОСТиТ, Касса, Прочее);<br>
\n\r№*****, ДО наименование – с 00.00.2016 г., (СОБ, ОСТиТ, Касса, Прочее);"`. Там где <br> остался перенос (не знаю как тут в комментариях добавить перенос строки)

Comment: Тогда удалите из строки еще `\r`: `$sms_text = str_replace("\r", "", str_replace("\n", "\\n", $sms_text));`